# Ajax call always getting failed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dialogsf() {
     $("#loadingsf").dialog({
         hide: 'slide',
         show: 'slide',
         autoOpen: true
     });
     $("#loadingsf").dialog('open').html("<p>Please Wait while contacts are imported...</p>");
     //alert("dfsd");
 }
 var fd = 1;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     dialogsf();
     $.ajax({
         url: "get_contacts.php",
         type: "GET",
         data: {
             sid: 'a'
         },
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         success: function (response) {
             // alert("Import done successfully with "+contacts.length+ " contacts");
             alert("Import done successfully");
             $('#loadingsf').html("<p>Result Complete...</p>");
         }
     }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
         alert('error:' + status + ':' + error + ':' + xhr.responseText)

     }).done(function (respond) {
         location.href = respond;

     });

 });
</script>
    <body >
    <div id="loadingsf" title="SF Contact Import"> 
    <p>Please wait ...</p>
</div>
```

This is the piece of snippet I am working on.
When I run the specific page I got this `"error:error::"`
Not sure why the ajax call is always failed and the console is empty too

Comment: please try commented this func. **//dialogsf();**

Comment: @maverabilisim i want a dialog box to appear while tha ajax call is being made

Comment: create a fiddle please.

Comment: All right. plesae try to like this case.

**var data = 'id='+ id  & 'name='+ name; 
data:data,**

Comment: @SarathSprakash where would I write  php?

Comment: @maverabilisim no logic behind this use

Comment: @user1765876 What is your jQuery version?

Comment: @user1765876, you can specify the url as '/echo/json/', in ajax call in the fiddle

Comment: @SarathSprakash it says import done successully.. http://jsfiddle.net/vNB8M/

Comment: @SarathSprakash i expect these are the required imports only right?   <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: @user1765876 the above fiddle is just a dialog ui, there is no ajax call

Comment: @user1765876 yes, only the jquery and the ui-widget plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `contentType:false` or set proper contentType as `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: When I run the specific page I got this "error:error::" - means there is no response from server side. Please check your server side method. And, make sure the passed argument in ajax call matches the parameter in server side method. If possible please add the server side methods structure.

Comment: my server side code has a else condition as well, that should run if nothing runs